# Can't read files in Flutter on all platforms, the file can be seen on linux desktop but web(chrome) does not see it, nor does android

Tags: android, flutter, file, dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

Future<Map?> readFile(lang) async {
  var pathToFile = join(dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath()), 'text', '$lang.toml');
  var document = File(pathToFile);
  return document;
}
```

So I have a text directory in my flutter root directory which contains some TOML files, I have no trouble accessing these files on linux but as soon as I run this on android I get a `(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`, and same on web but without the error message, it just returns null, I have also tried this as well:

```
var document = File('text/$lang.toml');
```

once again, same result.
I have seen people use the path_provider package for this but it didn't work anyway, and I would also like to have web compatibility. Anyone know how to solve this? TY

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to read a file on the host system or a file that is shipped in your code base as an asset?

Comment: A file that is shipped in my code base as an asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using shipped assets, you shouldn't use the host's file system. Instead use the `rootBundle` from `flutter/services`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

...

Future<String> readFile(String lang) {
  return rootBundle.loadString('text/$lang.toml');
}
```

Assuming the file is in a `text/` directory at the root of your project and it is defined in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - text/
```

The fact that it worked on Linux is kind of a coincidence, since you're running and developing on the same machine. This solution should work independent of which platform you're targeting.